# OpenVPN: how to suppress "WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this"

Tags: passwords, vpn, openvpn

In OpenVPN GUI, I am getting the red message

> WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this.

I do *not* want to always re-type my password again and again. Is there a way to **suppress** the warning **without** using the `auth-nocache` option?

I do not want to get myself used to permanently ignoring a red warning in the log dialog. This bad habit might prevent me from noticing an actual issue in the future. Like we have `@SuppressWarning` in Java for exactly the same reason.

I want to emphasize that I am not choosing between security and convenience, but I am asking for *higher security*! Multiple internet sources I found on this warning tell that the risk is minimal. However the risk that I become used to ignoring warnings seems much higher to me.

Comment: If you dont care about the security aspects of this, then you should most likly ask the question on a different SE. Possibly Superuser.se or Serverfault.se

Comment: None, that I'm aware of. Using this option will lead to an inability to automatically restart a failed connection.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov See the accepted answer, there is a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your login and password to the text file
`login.txt`
and add option
`auth-user-pass login.txt`
to your config.
This suppress login window and you can use `auth-nocache` option without reasking password.

Comment: Your solution works. 
I just added `auth-nocache` as the warning message suggests, and modified `auth-user-pass` to `auth-user-pass login.txt` as you suggested.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that reason you don't want to use `auth-nocache` is that it forces you to re-enter the password every hour when the key is re-negotiated. This, however, is something that can be changed. We use the following solution to get rid of the "red warning message" without having to store username and password locally (as the other answer suggests):

1. Add `auth-nocache` to the client configuration.
2. Add `reneg-sec 36000` to **both** the client and the server configuration (the default is 3600, and the smaller of the two values will be used).

This changes the key renegotiation timeout from 1 hour to 10 hours (which is enough for one work day).

Note that this (obviously) lowers encryption security. I still consider it a net win security-wise, since training my users to ignore warnings written in red would be even worse.

Comment: No, this was not my case. With plain `auth-nocache` I just had to re-enter the credentials only every time I *connected* to the VPN. And I cannot change the server settings, that's the constraint.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: Ah, ok. I'll leave my answer here anyways, in case it's useful for anyone finding this issue via Google.